# passing two sets of errors into page laravel undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How do I pass in two different types of $errors collection on a redirect back to the same page. The problem I'm having is with the variationErrors variable, the error is Undefined variable: variationErrors this happens on my blade view page

Controller:

```
    $variations = Input::get("variations");
    $variationErrors = [];
    // dd($variations);
    foreach ($variations as $id) {

        $data = [
            'producttype' => Input::get('producttype_' . $id),
            'price' => Input::get('price_' . $id),
            'quantity' => Input::get('quantity_' . $id),
            'discount' => Input::get('discount_' . $id)
        ];

        $validationVariations = Validator::make(
            $data,
            ProductVariations::$rules,
            ProductVariations::$rulesMessages
        );

        if($validationVariations->fails()) {
            $variationsHasErrors = true;

            $variationErrors[$id] = $validationVariations->messages()->toArray();

        }
    }

    if($validationProduct->fails() OR $variationsHasErrors) {           
        // problem here passing $variationErrors on blade page undefined $variationErrors
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validationProduct, $variationErrors)->withInput(); // ->with(compact('productsVariations'));
    }
```

Page:

```
{{ var_dump($variationErrors) }}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Try this please.

```
$variations = Input::get("variations");
$variationErrors = [];
// dd($variations);
foreach ($variations as $id) {

    $data = [
        'producttype' => Input::get('producttype_' . $id),
        'price' => Input::get('price_' . $id),
        'quantity' => Input::get('quantity_' . $id),
        'discount' => Input::get('discount_' . $id)
    ];

    $validationVariations = Validator::make(
        $data,
        ProductVariations::$rules,
        ProductVariations::$rulesMessages
    );

    if($validationVariations->fails()) {
        $variationsHasErrors = true;

        $variationErrors[] = $validationVariations->messages()->toArray();

    }
}

if(!empty($variationErrors)) {           
    // problem here passing $variationErrors on blade page undefined $variationErrors
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($variationErrors); // ->with(compact('productsVariations'));
}
```

Comment: it says illegal offset

Comment: I removed `$validationProduct` because I don't see it anywhere.  If it's another array of errors, you can add it to `$variationErrors`.

Comment: You didn't post all of the code.  I don't see validationProduct.